# FlatSpec displays strange behaviour while using 'should contain only'

Tags: scala, contains, scalatest

I have a simple test where i test if a specific array only contains 2 items.

`testArray should contain only (item1, item2)`

item1 is a Java object which has a field that can only be set with a setter, not through the constructor.

if i instantiate object 1 like this:

```
val item1 = new Item1("value1")
item1.setScheme("value2)
```

The test succeeds saying it does contain the object.

However if i instantiate object1 like this:

```
val item1 = new Item1("value1") {
   setScheme("value2")
}
```

the test fails. While the scheme value is still set in the same manner.
A `println(item1)` result in `item1(value='value1', scheme='value2')` in both cases

Does anyone know why FlatSpec treats these cases differently?

The code for Item1 (slightly Renamed fields for compliancy reasons)

```
public class Item1 extends LanguageTokenizedString {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8903312231226570431L;
  protected String scheme;

  public Item1() {
  }

  public Item1(String value) {
    super(value);
  }

  public Item1(String value, String language) throws InvalidLanguageTokenException {
    super(value, language);
  }

  public Item1(String value, Locale locale) throws InvalidLanguageTokenException {
    super(value, locale);
  }

  public Item1(String value, String language, String scheme) throws InvalidLanguageTokenException {
    super(value, language);
    this.setScheme(scheme);
  }

  public Item1(String value, Locale locale, String scheme) throws InvalidLanguageTokenException {
    super(value, locale);
    this.setScheme(scheme);
  }

  public String getScheme() {
    return this.scheme;
  }

  public final void setScheme(String scheme) {
    this.scheme = scheme;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean equals = false;
    if (obj != null) {
      if (obj == this) {
        equals = true;
      } else if (obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
        Item1 other = (Item1)obj;
        equals = (new EqualsBuilder()).append(this.value, other.value).append(this.scheme, other.scheme).append(this.schemeId, other.schemeId).append(this.language, other.language).isEquals();
      }
    }

    return equals;
  }

  public boolean shallowEquals(Object obj) {
    boolean shequals = false;
    if (obj != null) {
      if (obj == this) {
        shequals = true;
      } else if (obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
        Item1 other = (Item1)obj;
        shequals = (new EqualsBuilder()).append(this.value, other.value).append(this.scheme, other.scheme).append(this.schemeId, other.schemeId).isEquals();
      }
    }

    return shequals;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return (new HashCodeBuilder(23, 29)).append(this.value).append(this.scheme).append(this.schemeId).append(this.language).toHashCode();
  }

  public boolean isComplete() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Has `equals` been overridden for `Item1`? Can you post the code of `Item1`?

Comment: @MarioGalic posted the code of the legacy java Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getClass` on anonymous subclass differs from `getClass` on base class. For example

```
val itemA = new Item1("value1")
itemA.setScheme("value2")

val itemB = new Item1("value1") {
  setScheme("value2")
}

println(itemA.getClass)
println(itemB.getClass)
println(itemA.getClass == itemB.getClass)
```

should output

```
class example.Item1
class example.HelloSpec$$anon$1
false
```

where we see `getClass` differs for the two. This makes overridden `Item1.equals` fail on the following check

```
if (obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) ...
```

which makes ScalaTests's equality assertions fail.

Comment: I wasn't aware the second type of instantiation returned an Anon class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are different solutions.

```
val item1 = new Item1("value1")
item1.setScheme("value2)
```

returns `item1.setScheme("value2)`

And

```
val item1 = new Item1("value1") {
  setScheme("value2")
}
```

does `setScheme("value2")` inside `new Item1("value1")` and returns `new Item1("value1")`

**Example**

```
case class Item1(a: String){
  def setScheme(a:Int): Int ={
    a
  }
}

val item10: Item1 = new Item1("value1"){
  setScheme(1)
}
item10.a: String
item10.setScheme(1): Int

val item11 = new Item1("value1")
val item2: Int = item11.setScheme(1)
item2
```

The type of `item10` is `Item1`(The `case class`), when you use `{}`, you call inside `Item1` but the result is not a `String` or an `Int`, the result is the `case class`. You can use `{}` to operate inside the `case class` but allways you will recive the `case class`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, however i still don't really understand how this exactly causes the test to fail. Both methods result to a val that point to an object with the exact same properties. I also tried your example but the compiler than simply say you cannot assign a unit to a null type. Which is logical since a setter returns a void (Unit).

Comment: I will explain with a new example